# Adding a new rule in conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

**Table Context:**

I currently have an excel sheet that looks like this:
[image: this].

The sheet is full of formulas that pull relevant course information from another tab.

Moreover, I have set conditional formatting rules so that each course number (B8XXX) is given its respective color. You can see an example of that here:
[image: here.]

**My Question:**

I am trying to set a conditional formatting rule such that the adjacent cells that display "OPEN" correspond to the length of a class by removing the text "OPEN" and applying the same color as the course.

To be more clear, here's an example:

[image: Here]

1. ^ Here the class length is 1.30 hrs, but the cell doesn't span over to the 10:30 time slot in cell C3.
2. I want to apply a conditional formatting such that cell C5 reads the "Class Length: 1.30 hrs" in cell B5 and removes the "OPEN" text, and applies the same color format in cell B5 to cell C5. So, cell B5 AND cell C5 are the same color blue.
3. But I also want the conditional formatting to read the class length for classes that span 3.15 hrs, so that it spans across 10:30-12:15. So, (below) , the orange formatting should be applied to cell C11, D11, and E11.
   [image: here]

EDIT: Course Information

The course information is pulled from another table below it, which is pulled from a tab that has filtered a bunch of data.

1. Conditionally formatted table:
   [image: 5]]
2. Table below it:
   [image: 6]]
3. The tab where the information is coming from is:
   [image: 7]]

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you pull the class length from

Comment: will update with screenshots. thanks

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad updated with screenshot. hope it helps.